# What type of variable is file size?

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, discrete-data

Variables can be  discrete or continuous. Discrete variables are variables obtained by counting. Continuous variables are generated by measuring something.

My variable is "file size" and I believe that this is discrete (smallest measurement unit is one bit). I have read several questions that address types of statistical variables and followed recommended links and now I am confused :).

Discrete data are numeric data that have a finite number of possible values.

For example my dataset contains data from my disc and smallest file is less than 1 KB and biggest is 7 GB.... but if I think about variable globally as file size it is more limited to storage space. So if there is no upper limit is this a discrete variable?

I want to make bins and count my files to see file distribution on my disk.

I believe that if I have some time variable (Continuous data .. this is for sure), and use this variable to track something through time it s continuous data (stock market), but if I count how many events happened in time window that this is discrete variable - is this misleading?
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
extension

Regarding my dilemma about file size measure. I collected data from one workstation (pc14) about user file size. And according to some previouse research try to fit this data to some distribution from continuous family of distributions. Previous research suggested to use lognormal distribution, while other used mixture of Pareto and lognormal. I did find that Frechet  is closest to my dataset but still with high AIC. When I tryed to generate dataset with estimated parameters  KS test showed real small P value.

Then I observed this as discrete variable. And this are results.

```
> descdist(pc14, discrete = TRUE, boot = 5000)
summary statistics
------
min:  714   max:  23599220 
median:  54778 
mean:  159834.3 
estimated sd:  657485.3 
estimated skewness:  18.40947 
estimated kurtosis:  496.2262
```

[image]

```
> fitnb <- fitdist(pc14, "nbinom", lower = c(0.0))
$start.arg
$start.arg$size
[1] 0.05911125

$start.arg$mu
[1] 159834.3


$fix.arg
NULL

>s1 <- rnbinom(4244, size = fitnb$estimate["size"], mu = fitnb$estimate["mu"])
> chisq.test(s1,pc14)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  s1 and pc14
X-squared = 5267748, df = 5264535, p-value = 0.1611

Warning message:
In chisq.test(s1, pc14) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I know that 16% is not high,  but H0 can be accepted if p > 0.05% , that data coming from same distribution.

My dilemma is greater now :) is this prof that file size is discrete value (since I managed to map to find better match with discrete distribution), or I misinterpret the data and results?

Comment: Why do you care? How are you going to use it?

Comment: Even if there is no upper limit to the disc size i.e, storage space, one can take this variable as discrete. It is about the discrete count. Example, Natural numbers are infinite in count but discrete.

Comment: @Tim I am looking for distribution so i can use for simulation pseudo generator. I want to make bins, count files and then look for underlaying distribution.

Comment: I did find this paper (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1999/01/Sigmetrics1999.pdf) and for file size they use two distributions that are related to continues variables.

Comment: The population of countries is surely discrete, but populations are oftenreported rounded because anything else would be spurious precision and may not what authorities know any way. This is an old chestnut: in principle file size is discrete; in practice it is likely to be reported in rounded form; in practice whether it can be treated as continuous depends on how it behaves.

Comment: The old distinction between counting (children, cats, pencils) and measuring (with a ruler or thermometer or some instrument) is always a good start. As I understand it, more and more measurements are at machine level based on counting, with hardware and software combined to report a number with decimal places, so the distinction is blurring.

Comment: If I use file size in bits ( you can t divided more since bit is basic element) and can take "rounded value" 0 or 1, this leads me to discrete variable. But paper I mention (link i posted) treat this as continues variable (probably because theoretically  since there is no top boundaries) . Hard decision to make :)

Comment: I don't think whether there is an upper limit is decisive. The question is how many distinct values there are and what kind of analysis you intend. There is much literature intended to be helpful on what methods may or should be used with which kinds of variables but the more you learn, the more you learn exceptions.  For example, module marks in education are arguably not even ordinal -- confidence that my 79% means "better work" than Professor X's 78% is certainly lacking -- but in practice every institution known to me treats such marks as if they wee essentially continuous.

Comment: For me it s confusing that continuous "take forever to count", or as wiki say "A continuous variable is a variable whose value is obtained by measuring, ie one which can take on an uncountable set of values."  since when we store file on disk, it s limited to disk capacity so theoretically could take "uncountable set of values" but it s hardly true. I done research and many researcher follow this practice and mark them as continuous variable and relay on  log-normal distribution or hyperexponential distribution.

Comment: If we look at a continuous variable as a variable that changes continuously over time, then file size can be classified as discrete variable.  Here is an example, We have a file size of 1 KB, then the file size does not change for a long time and then the user edits the file and the size jumps to 2 KB, the value did not grow over time from 1 KB to 2 KB size, even if we understand how PC works, then we know that file is loaded in RAM memory, and by modifying file, that file dynamicly allocate more memory but still in discrete step (block, register etc)

Answer (score 2):

Weight and height are also continuous, even if in practice they can only be measured as units of grams (g) or millimeters (mm). It's more related to the nature of the variable, not as much to the particular data. In my opinion, data storage could be understood as continuous (two files are quite unlikely to have the same size, and bits or bytes are quite small). For comparison, I would treat the number of files in folders as discrete.

Comment: Counted variable as number of files is for sure discrete variable but weight can be expressed as miligram, if we measure small amount it could reach picogram, but it s more  related to the fact that we can say it s 5,666666666.... grams that s related to continuous nature If I understand correctly. But you can not say that file 56, 88888 bits.